# Where to find power option config file(s) for 17.10

Tags: 17.10, power-management, monitor, settings, configure

Just upgraded to 17.10 because 17.04 hit EOL. Seems really nice except for one small basic thing that baffles me as to why it's hard-coded. The amount of time before the monitor goes blank (for some reason it doesn't give the option to turn off monitor but it seems monitor does turn off after it's blank for a while) gives a handful of hard-coded options in a drop down. The max is 15 minutes. I need 30. Where can I find a config file to manually set that value?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to this super user [answer](https://superuser.com/questions/727120/make-gnome-screen-lock-after-1-hour-not-15-minutes):

You can set the desired settings in GSettings directly.

Timeout for blanking the screen (seconds; 0 = never):

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.session idle-delay 1800
```

Timeout for locking the screen after blanking (seconds; 0 = instant):

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.screensaver lock-delay 0
```

Comment: Cheers! I've set that setting. I'll mark the fix as fixed after I observe it work once.

Comment: @gord0 See you again in 30 minutes...